# Spring integration - sftp:outbound-channel-adapter - dynamic sftpSessionFactory?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

How to make sftpSessionFactory dynamic based on the file? For example, if filename starts with A, this file has to be placed on a particular SFTP location, for B, C, D type files has their own SFTP locations. So I have 4 different host/user/password/port, as an example, I picked up 4, but I may have more than 20 type of files. I can't hardcode host/user/password/port values in application.properties file or in integration.xml file.

On spring boot server startup, I get all those sftp configuration details from config server as a Map.

```
Map<String, SftpValues> values = getAllSftpValues(); // this connects to a config server to fetch all type of sftp details.
SftpValues sftpValues = values.get("A");
```

`sftpValues` ==> these values i should be able to set into DefaultSftpSessionFactory dynamically and pass sftpSessionFactory on to outbound-channel-adapter for each and every file.

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="user" value="user01"/>
    <property name="password" value="abc123"/>
    <property name="port" value="990"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel"/>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="#{T(System).getProperty('java.io.tmpdir')}" id="fileInbound"
                              channel="sftpChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                   channel="sftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="/"
                                   remote-file-separator="/"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> set into DefaultSftpSessionFactory dynamically

That's not correct. You cannot mutate the session factory. What you can do is to utilize a `DelegatingSessionFactory` approach.

You configure it for some set of delegates: `public DelegatingSessionFactory(Map<Object, SessionFactory<F>> factories, SessionFactory<F> defaultFactory) {`. And then you call its `public Message<?> setThreadKey(Message<?> message, Object key) {` before sending to the `<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>` and then its `public Message<?> clearThreadKey(Message<?> message) {` after or as a second subscriber of the `publish-subscribe-channel` for that `sftpOutboundAdapter`.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-dsf

Comment: DelegatingSessionFactory is a Bean object, but I have delegates that are dynamic in nature. I might delete a delegate (decommission SFTP location) or add a delegate (adding a new SFTP location). In that case, how do I update DelegatingSessionFactory dynamically?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem you see with that `DelegatingSessionFactory`. To add dynamically, you just do `((DefaultSessionFactoryLocator) DelegatingSessionFactory.getFactoryLocator()).addSessionFactory(Object key, SessionFactory<F> factory)`. Why that API doesn't work for you?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Just a final question, how to make remote-directory dynamic in int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter ? with your help I made all the parameters(host/user/password/port) dynamic, except the remote-directory, I don't find it in DefaultSftpSessionFactory.

Comment: See a `remote-directory-expression`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#spel-and-the-sftp-outbound-adapter

Comment: sorry for the late response, i tried to fetch remote directory at runtime, using this code, the flow doesn't enter `determineRemoteDirectory` method :     `<bean id="sftpConfig" class="com.sftp.ConfigList"/>

    <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="dsf"
                                       channel="outsftpChannel" charset="UTF-8"
                                       remote-directory-expression="@sftpConfig.determineRemoteDirectory(headers['file_name'])" />`

Comment: Well, it cannot be just silent: you probably should see some errors in logs after running your application and producing a file for transfer.

Comment: yes, that was a naive known_hosts mistake. I am able to upload the file now!!! Small observation, is there any way we can add a handler to outbound-channel-adapter? once the file is uploaded it has to trigger a success method or in case of any error, it has to invoke an error method of the Handler class. Based on the response, I need to perform an action on the file.

Comment: See this component and its whole chapter how to apply : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice